# Is multiple function overloading not permitted with virtual functions?

Tags: c++

My program compiles fine, but gets core dumped when an overloaded function is called. Below, is the output of the program:

```
FoodID supplied=1
FoodBase constructor called
In K constructor
In Omlette constructor
Omlette handler constructor called
In prepare() Omlette Handler
Mix called
K Prepare called
K Egg called
DonePreparing called
In egg() Omlette Handler
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm trying to overload the pure virtual function named "egg". The egg function needs to be of two types: One that takes no variables and the other that takes an integer. The one that takes the integer crashes. Help?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class K
{
    public:
    K() {cout<<"In K constructor"<<endl;}

    protected:
    void kPrepare() {cout<<"K Prepare called"<<endl;}
    void kEgg() {cout<<"K Egg called"<<endl;}
};

class Omlette : public K
{
    public:
    Omlette() {cout<<"In Omlette constructor"<<endl;}

    protected:
    void doPreparation()
    {
        mix();
        kPrepare();
        kEgg();
        donePreparing();
    }
    void mix() {cout<<"Mix called"<<endl;}
    void donePreparing() {cout<<"DonePreparing called"<<endl;}  
};

class FoodBase
{
    public:
    virtual void prepare()=0;
    virtual void egg()=0;
    virtual void egg(int)=0;

    FoodBase() {cout<<"FoodBase constructor called"<<endl;}

};

class OmletteHandler : public FoodBase, Omlette
{   
    public:
    OmletteHandler() {cout<<"Omlette handler constructor called"<<endl;}
    void prepare() 
    {
        cout<<"In prepare() Omlette Handler"<<endl;
        doPreparation();//from Omlette class
    }
    void egg() {cout<<"In egg() Omlette Handler"<<endl;}
    void egg(int i) {cout<<"In egg("<<i<<") Omlette Handler"<<endl;}
};

class Food
{
    public:
    FoodBase *base;

    Food(int foodID)//getting foodID from commandline just for testing purpose
    {
        OmletteHandler immediate;//changed from 'imm' to 'immediate'
        base=&immediate;
    }//Food

    void prepare() {base->prepare();}
    void egg() {base->egg();}
    void egg(int i) {base->egg(i);}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int foodID=1;
    if (argc>1) {foodID = atoi(argv[1]);}

    cout<<"FoodID supplied="<<foodID<<endl; 

    Food f(foodID);
    f.prepare();
    f.egg();
    f.egg(10);

}//main
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Food constructor you create an OmeletteHandler on the stack, this gets destroyed once the function exits.

```
Food(int foodID)//getting foodID from commandline just for testing purpose 
{ 
    OmletteHandler imm; 
    base=&imm; 
}//
```

You could do `base = new OmeletteHandler()` instead, (don't forget to delete the pointer later or you'll have memory leak).

Comment: I was wondering how come call to void prepare() {base->prepare();}
was success?

Comment: Even I was puzzled at that. I think it's because the calls to the functions happened quicker than it got removed from the stack. Can anyone confirm that? I tried placing destructors in all classes and this time, the constructors of all classes got called, then immediately the destructors got called and then these lines got printed: "pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)"

Comment: @user453673 No, `imm` was indeed popped off the stack before `prepare` was called. However in the original code, nothing that happens in `OmletteHandler::prepare` actually accesses any part of the `OmletteHandler` object itself. Its just a bunch of calls to `cout`. The `this` pointer would be pointing to stack memory that can already been reclaimed for other use, but nothing actually accesses that memory during `prepare`. So due to how C++ compilers typically implement member functions, that code can run just fine for the moment.

Comment: Of course, even if it appears to run fine, calling a member function through a pointer to a dead object is bad and should be avoided. If you want to learn a bit more about this detail, try searching SO for questions about calling member functions through NULL pointers.